# HTML Anchor, Disable Style

Tags: html, css, anchor

I have some html anchor link code, and unlike the rest of document I want it to look like it is not a link.

Is there a simple way to disable the style change caused by wrapping text in a anchor tag without having to brute force it to be the same (ie, if I change the body font style I don't have to also change some other :link stuff).

Comment: In addition to the below answers, you can add `display: contents` to the `a` anchor element which will take the styles of its contents, which is useful in the case of `img` images.

Answer (score 121, accepted):

Setting color to black and text-decoration to explicitly none is a little more aggressive than worked for me.

I was looking for the CSS of the anchors to be "benign" and just blend into the existing CSS.  Here's what I went with:

```
a.nostyle:link {
    text-decoration: inherit;
    color: inherit;
    cursor: auto;
}

a.nostyle:visited {
    text-decoration: inherit;
    color: inherit;
    cursor: auto;
}
```

Then I just added the CSS nostyle class to the anchors that I wanted to be unformatted.

Comment: This works even without the `:link` (which the `<a>` tag kind of is by default anyway.)

Comment: You could combine these to reduce duplication: a.nostyle:link, a.nostyle:visited { ... }

Comment: @AlexisWilke using :link refers to link with href never visited.  If you want to use all links even without href (my pref to avoid '#' refs causing change of pages URL and other side-effects).  See https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_link.asp

Answer (score 11):

I achieved this by creating a class `.reset-a` and targeting all of its' pseudo classes.

Targeting of all pseudo classes is important to make it flawless.

`outline: 0` property removes the dotted border that surrounds a link when it is focused or active.

```
.reset-a, .reset-a:hover, .reset-a:visited, .reset-a:focus, .reset-a:active  {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: inherit;
  outline: 0;
  cursor: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

If you don't care about IE, you can attach `:not(#exclude)` (where `exclude` is the ID of the link in question) to your link styles:

```
a:link:not(#exclude), a:visited:not(#exclude) {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: blue;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Otherwise I don't think you can brute-force it the way you describe. You can either use an inline style instead (not recommended) or you can use a special class/ID assigned to that link, whose selector you'd group with `body`. For example, if you had these styles:

```
body {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
    cursor: auto;
}

a:link, a:visited {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: blue;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

You can simply toss in a more specific selector, that'd match that link, onto the `body` rule:

```
body, #exclude {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
    cursor: auto;
}

a:link, a:visited {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: blue;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a handy snippet if you want to copy-paste the accepted solution into React

```js
const UnstyledLink = ({ href, children }) => (
  <a
    href={href}
    style={{
      textDecoration: "inherit",
      color: "inherit",
      cursor: "auto",
    }}
  >
    {children}
  </a>
);
```