# Rotate on Click to Show Info

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

This is my first question, so please go easy on me.  I am trying to make a Tumblr theme in which the posts rotate on the y-axis to show the like and reblog info when you click on them.  I have managed to make it so that this happens on hover using the code from [here](http://css3.bradshawenterprises.com/flip/), but as I mentioned, I want to make it so that it happens on click.  I've seen a couple of tutorials on how to do this with Javascript or jQuery, but I can't get them to work.  So can someone please explain how to do this, in the simplest way possible/in layman's terms, because I am very new to Javascript and jQuery?
Thanks so much!
Here is my CSS:

```
    #f1_container {
  position: relative;
  margin: 10px auto;
  width: 250px;
  z-index: 1;


  perspective: 1000;
}
#f1_card {
  width: 250px;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transition: all 1.3s linear;


}

#f1_container:hover #f1_card {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
.face {
  position: absolute;

  backface-visibility: hidden;
}
.face.back {
position:absolute;  transform: rotateY(180deg);
background-color:{color:Text};
  width:250px;
  top:0;
  height:100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  text-align: center;

}
```

...and here is some HTML:

```
{block:Photo}
{block:IndexPage}
<div id="f1_container">
<div id="f1_card">
  <div class="photo"><div class="front-face"><img src="{PhotoURL-250}" alt="{PhotoAlt}"> </div></div> <div class="back face center">
<div class="perm"><span class="like"style="padding-right:7px">{LikeButton color="grey" size="13"}</span> <span class="rb" style="padding-left:5px;">{ReblogButton color="grey" size="13"}</span> <span class="noteslabel" style="padding-right:5px;"><a href="{Permalink}" target="_blank">{NoteCount}</a></li></ol></div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
{/block:IndexPage}
{block:PermalinkPage} <img src="{PhotoURL-500}" alt="{PhotoAlt}"> {/block:PermalinkPage} {/block:Photo}
```

Edit: Here is the link to the page: http://shimmeringdaydreams.tumblr.com.  (Sorry it's kind of a mess right now; this is just where I test out my themes that I'm making, and I'm in the middle of making this one.)

Comment: tumblr lets you include JS in the themes?

Comment: In your CSS, try changing `#f1_container:hover` to `#f1_container:focus`. Does that help any?

Comment: did you include modernizr? it's a script

Comment: download it here http://modernizr.com/

Comment: @RachelGallen I tried but I don't think it's what I need.  Thanks, though.

Answer (score 0):

I think Ramsay was on the right track with :focus.  Try wrapping f1_container in an anchor like this:

```
<a href="#" class="focus-wrapper"> <!--also stop re-using IDs - they're supposed to be unique-->
  <div class="f1_container"> 
     <!-- just pretend I copy+pasted stuff in here -->
  </div>
</a>
```

And then remove the special anchor styles as in [HTML Anchor, Disable Style](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6868009/html-anchor-disable-style):

```
.focus-wrapper:hover, .focus-wrapper:visited {
   text-decoration: inherit;
   color: inherit;
   cursor: auto;
}
```

Then make a rule to make the change on focus:

```
.focus-wrapper:focus .f1_container .f1_card {
   transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
```

And remove the browser's focus outline:

```
.focus-wrapper:focus {
   outline:none;
}
```

Also, in case it's not clear, you'd **take out** the rule that looks like:

```
#f1_container:hover #f1_card {
   transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
```

Ugly example: http://jsfiddle.net/yb9exv9b/

Comment: Thanks for your help, but unfortunately this did not work for me.  When I click on the posts, nothing happens.

Comment: Can you post a link to a live page?

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mistaken, I'm pretty sure Tumblr allows jQuery and Javascript integration.
At the head of your file, put this:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

This will allow you to use jQuery. Now, all you have to do is write the click function:

```
var r=0;
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#Image-ID-or-DIV').click(function(){   
        $("#Image-ID-or-DIV").css("transition", "500ms linear all");                    
        $("#imgs").css({transform: 'rotateY(' + (r += 180) + 'deg)'});
    });
});
```

0) The r=0 will play a big factor in resetting the animation once it is done.

1) Document.ready is a basic jQuery function, nothing special

2) This states that when the Image (must have an ID) is clicked, a function will be executed.

3) This states that when the image is clicked, the transitions it will have will be 500 milliseconds long (subject to change to your liking) and will go smoothly.

4) The actual rotating of the image happens here. Read some  [documentation](http://www.javascriptkit.com/dhtmltutors/css3-transitions-and-jquery.shtml)  about this. Basically, This states that upon click, the images css will change so that it will rotate r + 180 degrees (r is 0, but it resets the animation, so this is crucial).

If you need to add more css to when the image is clicked, just add:

```
$("#Image-ID-or-DIV").css('[css goes here]')
```

But you might want to look at some [documentation,](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_css.asp) as different rules apply to jQuery .css().

I hope this was of some help to you!

Comment: All you'd do is toggle a class in this case since they already have CSS transitions working